# Inter communication between widgets in orchard

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

is there way in orchard to intercommunicate between custom widget?

Scenario :-

Suppose :- We have one widget name teacher . which can add student name . on same page we have second widget name student . while teacher add new student name it will show in second widget (student) on same page . on second page we have also dragged student widget it should be also update with new value .i would not to store value in database . Please help me out . 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Why do they need to be separate widgets? Why do they even need to be widgets? Where is the first widget getting its data from? Why couldn't the second one get its data from the same place?

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy 3   actually  i have requirement like this. Means . when first widget getting update with new values , then all other widgets should be update with new value . one more Scenario :-  We have first widget with fields like date and time range. while i updated date time from first widget and navigate to next page . next page has same widget .next page widget fields should be  automatically update with value selected at last page . hope you under stand my concern . i am newbie with orchard not know most of its feature.You can suggest me any other way to do this in orchard Thanks

Comment: All your widgets are getting their data from somewhere. What I'm suggesting is that your widgets do not get their data from other widgets, but from a common, underlying common data source. This way, there is no need for communication between widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Orchard does not have anything *specific* to do this, but neither does it get in your way of doing it if you want to.

We have similar intra-communication in some of our widgets. We do it by adding a specific property to the widget (which can be changed by editing the widget) where we input the name of the widget to link to. In our case, the widgets we are using share a JSON object (the linked widget now knows the name of the widget it's linked to, so we can work out how to get the JSON object). We then use an observable style JS framework (I believe that our frontend devs are using marionette, but pick your flavour). If widget A or Widget B updates the JSON object, then the the html is automatically updated, due to how the JS framework works. This gives nice "interactive" widgets.

Alternatively - if you only care about the linking at the loading time, then both widgets should pull data from an interface implementing IDependency (e.g. IMyService) that is "per request", then you can easily share the data that way server side.

I'm guessing from your comments to Bertrand that you are looking for the first option I listed.

I'm sure you could take these concepts significantly further and get to SharePoints "linked parts" framework where as long as you link an output / input of the same data type it allows the linking, but that would be rather harder to complete.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Devenney i agree with you using IDependency . i had look on IRouteProvder it also share data in same way . but in this way we need to add data in  list every time as they are doing in Route.cs file they are adding fixed route  .but in my case data is coming dynamically  i am not aware which will be next value . can we apply in this case .please help me out .

Comment: if your data is "dynamic" (no new page request), then the JavaScript approach I mention should be appropriate. either populate the shared JSON object from the server request, followed by js filtering, or, asynchronously load everything (in which case the widget is really a box for some script). 
IRouteProvider is not really specifically relevant (other than it implements IDependency. If you want dynamic data, then get it from your data source the code you write for the implementation of your own interface is yours to control! . If you clarify your issue better I can probably help

Comment: Sure , Suppose we have one widget with two fields "StartDate , Enddate", and have second widget on same page with grid control to display list of employees. when user will select dates from first widget. second widget grid should be update automatically respect to selected date from first widget. And if second page has employee list widget and navigate to second page it should be also updated with respect to selected dates from previous page. hope its clear to you now . Thanks for your replies

Comment: ok - when you say "the widget has start date/end date" - I assume you mean "on the front end interface that normal site users use, rather than "the admin configuration for the widget". If I understand correctly you want it to work "within the page, across widgets" AND "across page requests". Is this information correct? (I'd also first ask how you would think to solve it if you were not in Orchard, as the solution has very little to do with orchard, other than the information is presented to the screen via "widgets"

Comment: Yes . you are correct . i can use querystring and session to pass information across  pages and widget. According to me. Do you have any other idea please share ?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for me ? Please let me know . Thanks

Comment: so do the two very specific techniques I've already mentioned not help you? I'm not sure what more you need?